# Linear dependence of following polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I was given the following problem and its solution in my textbook.

> Determine whether the polynomials
>
> $p_1=1−x$ ,   $p_2 = 5 + 3x −2x^2$, $p_3 = 1 + 3x - x^2 $
>
> are linearly dependent or linearly independent in $P_2$
>
> Solution: The linear independence or dependence of these vectors is
>   determined by whether the vector equation
>
> $k_1$$p_1$ + $k_2$$p_2$ + $k_3$$p_3$=0         (Equation 7)
>
> can be satisfied with coefficients that are not all zero. To see
>   whether this is so, let us rewrite (Equation 7) in its polynomial form
>
> $k_1$(1-x) + $k_2$($5 + 3x −2x^2$) + $k_3$($1 + 3x - x^2 $) = 0
>
> or, equivalently, as
>
> ($k_1+5k_2+k_3$)+($−k_1+3k_2+3k_3)x$ + ($−2k_2−k_3)x^2$
>
> Since this equation must be satisfied by all $x$ in
>   $(-\infty,\infty)$, each coefficient must be zero (as explained in the
>   previous example). Thus, the linear dependence or independence of the
>   given polynomials hinges on whether the following linear system has a
>   nontrivial solution:
>
> $k_1+5k_2+k_3$ = 0
>
> $−k_1+3k_2+3k_3 = 0$
>
> $−2k_2−k_3 = 0$
>
> We leave it for you to show that this linear system has nontrivial
>   solutions either by solving it directly or by showing that the
>   coefficient matrix has determinant zero.

I don't understand why after the equation was written in the polynomial form

$k_1$(1-x) + $k_2$($5 + 3x −2x^2$) + $k_3$($1 + 3x - x^2 $) = 0

it wasn't enough to say that the coefficients $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ must be 0 and so the the vectors are linearly INDEPENDENT. That extra step that it takes afterwards and the fact that it ends up being linearly dependent is really confusing to me, so I was wondering if anyone could clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you carry out the calculation that the solution left to you, find the non-trivial solutions of the linear system and confirm that substituting the solution into  the equation you re-quote at the end does indeed satisfy it. This, I hope, should convince you that concluding $k_1=k_2=k_3=0$ from this equation is unwarranted.

Comment: I think it was the term "coefficient" that was confusing me. I thought k1, k2 and k3 were the coefficients. But in a polynomial, the sum of the terms multiplied by x would be the coefficient of x (hence (-k1 + 3k2 + 3k3)x ), where -k1 + 3k2 + 3k3 is the coefficient of x, and the same for x^2, and I guess for the ones where they didn't have an x, it was because it was x^0.

Comment: What confuses me is that it seems to say that there are TWO ways of writing the polynomial form that are "equivalent"...where it says "let us rewrite (Equation 7) in its polynomial form k1(1-x)....etc , or equivalently as (k1+5k2 + k3)...etc ". Are they BOTH the polynomial form, or is only the second one the polynomial form?

Comment: @FrostyStraw: I don't know that there's any formal definition of the polynomial form of an equation. The phrasing seems a bit unfortunate; I can see how it confused you. If I had to call something "the polynomial form of the equation", that would be the second form (which is missing the "$=0$", by the way), but I'd probably use an entirely different formulation and say something like "let's group monomials together" or "let's collect the coefficients of the monomials".